# cross validation of GBT Classifier on PySpark taking too much time on 2 GB data(80% Train & 20 % Test). Is there a way to reduce the time?

Tags: python, pyspark, cross-validation

cross validation of GBT Classifier on PySpark taking too much time on 2 GB data(80% Train & 20 % Test). Is there a way to reduce the time?
The sample code is as given below:-

```py
dt = GBTClassifier(maxIter = 250)
pipeline_dt = Pipeline(stages=[indexer, assembler, dt])
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder().build()  
crossval = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline_dt, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
   evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),numFolds=6)    
   cvModel = crossval.fit(train_df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, evaluation is run in the serial manner - next round is done after previous is finished.  Starting with Spark 2.3, [there is a `parallelism` parameter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/ml-tuning.html) that specifies how many evaluations may run in parallel.

P.S. If you'll add parameter search as well, then I would recommend to look to the [Hyperopt library](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt) that improves hyperparameters search.